# MBP stuck at login page after wake up (doesn't transit to loading bars)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, sleep-wake, monterey

Running Monterey 12.0.1 on a 2019 MBP (refurb)

I have had this problem only pretty recently (fine otherwise, for about 1.75 years until the last few weeks; so perhaps a recent update? yet I can't find similar questions online)

So basically, sometimes when I open the lid from wake up, the MacBook prompts me to enter my password to login (specifically not allowing fingerprint id). I would be able to do so, either via the MBP keyboard or a BlueTooth Apple keyboard.

Once I hit enter, however, the page gets "stuck". The button to submit the password gets grayed out (unclickable) and it just gets stuck there without any notion of it processing or logging me in. Keys still work, as pressing random keys produce that "tak" bad input MacOS sound. I think I can still toggle brightness/audio, etc, but beyond that I'm locked out.

Any help? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: When was the last time you booted into Recovery mode and ran Disk Utility's "Verify Disk"?

Comment: Lots of odd problems with 12.01 have been fixed by updating to 12.1. I'd try that first [or second]

Comment: @Tetsujin ah thanks for the heads up, I've gone and done that. Strangely it was bugging out and my Mac wasn't finding new updates until I restarted and tried looking for updates a couple of times. Hope it fixes things.

Comment: @pion Never... Not really a Mac user so I have never heard of that. Let me look it up and do that, thanks!